# Java Class Object having string array property initialization

Tags: java, arrays

I have a POJO class with one of `String` array property having size is 2. But I am creating the object of `Person` class with passing array of size 5. It's not showing any exception. Why?

```
package classObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Person implements Cloneable {

    String name;
    int age;
    String[] skills = new String[2];

    Person() {

    }

    Person(String name, int age, String[] skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("this.skills.length " + this.skills.length);
        System.out.println("skills.length " + skills.length);
        this.skills = skills;
        System.out.println("Got array is " + Arrays.asList(this.skills));
        System.out.println("length of arrays is " + this.skills.length);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    protected Person clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Person) super.clone();
    }

    public String[] getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(String[] skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
}

// Creating the Object of Person Class
public class classObject {

    /* Way to create an object of any class */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Define the array with len 5
            String[] skills = new String[5];
            skills[0] = "Java";
            skills[1] = "PHP";
            skills[2] = "JDBC";
            skills[3] = "ORACLE";
            skills[4] = "SQL";
            // Passing the array
            Person objPerson = new Person("Mohit", 27, skills);
            System.out.println("Size is " + objPerson.skills.length);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you define/initialize the array correctly the compiler won't complain and no error occurs. However when you run your program with e.g. size more than what your array allows you are going to get a `RuntimeException` such as `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown when trying to get an item with index e.g. `2 or above` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[]` is an object, although it doesn't look like it. So when you declare.

```
String[] skills = new String[2];
```

You're actually declaring a pointer to a new object, which is a `String[]` object, with a size of `2`.

Then you come a long with a new `String[]` object of size `5`, and your reference now points to that.

This process has nothing to do with the original object, because when you state:

```
this.skills = skills;
```

you're not effecting the object that `this.skills` points to; only the pointer itself. The `String[2]` object will have no pointers referring to it, and the garbage collector will likely come a long and destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

You're pointing the class variable to the argument passed in the function... Check its' size in the constructor and if it's not 2, then throw IllegalArgumentExepction.